# Iterate a series of variables which have incremented numeric suffixes

Tags: php, variable-variables

There are 10 variables. say `$var1, $var2, $var3, $var4,....$var10`

and a `$count` variable. what I am looking for is if all variables are set then `$count = 10+1` or if 9 variables only set then `$count=9+1` or if 8 variables only set then `$count=8+1`  and so on last up to 1 variable(for one variable is set then `$count = 1+1`).

I know do this with `if`, `elseif` and `else` but I need to write too much line of code.

Does any one know how to do this in brief code??

Comment: Yes.  I know how to do this "in brief code".

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes? The question is perfectly clear and valid.

Comment: I think because it looks like homework mi hermano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
$arr = array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6, $var7, $var8, $var9, $var10);
$count = 1;
foreach ($arr as $v)
{
    if (isset($v))
        $count++;
}
```

Comment: But where do you check if this variables are set or not??

Comment: @mathew: See the call to `isSet`?

Comment: ``$var1, $var2,...``
might not have been initialized. You can't put them into an array.

Comment: @Willi: sure you can.  An array entry can be null, last i heard.  Now, it may trigger a warning, so if you don't like that, yeah.  Could cause a slight problem.

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in PHP:

```
$count = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    if ( isset( ${'var'.$i} ) ) $count++;
}
```

Comment: @musicfreak: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/234170#234170

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  ...
$countarr = compact('var1', 'var2', ..., 'var10');
$count = count($countarr) + 1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Er... Are you aware that PHP allows to use loops...

```
<?php

$var1 = 100;
$var4 = 200;
$var9 = 600;

$count = 0;
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
    if( isset(${"var$i"}) ){
        $count++;
    }
}

echo $count;

?>
```

... and arrays?

```
<?php

$var = array(100, 200, 600);
$count = count($var);
echo $count;

?>
```

## Answer to Boreadlid's remarks

You should note that unsetting an array element is not the same as setting it to NULL. This code:

```
<?php

$data = array(10, 20, 30);
$data[1] = NULL;
unset($data[0]);
var_dump($data);

?>
```

... prints this:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  int(30)
}
```

... so `count($data)` prints `2` because it *is* a two element array.

Whatever the OP is trying to accomplish, he should probably be using arrays where unused values are never set to begin with. The `$var1, $var2, $var3` approach will work but it's not what a skilled programmer would do. *(Of course, there's nothing wrong in being a newbie.)*

Comment: I don't think `count` does what you think it does.

Comment: @Borealid: So it doesn't return the number of elements in the array?

Comment: @Alvaro: it does return the number of elements in the array.  But it will include ones which are `NULL`, or `false`.  Or otherwise "unset".

Comment: @Borealid: Why should values set to NULL or FALSE not be count as array items?

Comment: @Alvaro: Because in this particular problem, the author was looking for a way to determine if variables were set.

Answer (score -1):

you have 20 vars (10x "var" and 10x "tvar"):

```
bool[] vars = new bool[10];
bool[] tvars = new bool[10];
```

i don't get your +1 part in $count... but what about:

```
int count = 1; //includes the always needed +1 part
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   if(vars[i] && tvars[i])
      count += i+1; //so 0 => 1
```

??

Comment: this will do: 1, 2, 4, 7, 11, … (you probably meant `$count += 1`) and this is php, not c++ ;)

Comment: sorry - i've missed the PHP-tag...

...or maybe i just thought i'll answer

a stupid question with a stupid answer

(the -4 on the question hardens my point here xD)

sry - will not post without fearing negative
reputation anymore :)

*OMG* - look there - if he made a dollar-sign in front of his variable that code might even work... slay him for not making the dollar-sign!

@sAc&knittl: you both got comment++ from me :)